# How to change data in scope from angular websocket service?

Tags: angularjs, websocket

I have this service. And it get me error when I do $rootScope.$apply

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('AngularChatApp')
    .factory('WS', function($websocket, $rootScope, Online){

      var dataStream = $websocket("ws://"+apiconf.config.ws_server+"/ws");

      var collection = [];

      dataStream.onMessage(function(message) {
        message = JSON.parse(message.data)
        console.log(message);
        if(message.action=='update_users_online'){
            Online.getOnline(function(rezult){

                $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                    $rootScope.user_list = rezult.user_list;
                });
            })        
        }
      });

      dataStream.onOpen(function(message) {

      });

      var methods = {

        collection: collection,

        send: function(mess) {
          dataStream.send(JSON.stringify(mess));
        }

      };

      return methods;   

    });


})();
```

And I want to refresh user list in my page after particular message from websocket server.
To do this I need change scope in controller.
But how can I say to contoller that I want to do if I get message inside service not inside controller?

Comment: What's your question exactly? If your question is about an error, then post the complete and exact error you get. To notigy your controller, you could simply broadcast an event on the root scope. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast

Comment: what is `collection` for? What exactly is the issue? Why are you using $rootScope to store response? That's what your service is for and not maintaining only one reference array is likely what your problem is/ WHow controller code associated with the service

Comment: I get Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
Collection is redundant, sorry.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont know how to associate controller with service in case when an event starts inside my service. I will try to play with broadcast. Thank you.